# Extract the data description for disk drives

Tags: linux, text-processing, hard-disk

I had a requirement to get some details about the disk drive such as **"Model Number", "Serial Number" 
& "Firmware Revision"** and came to know hdparm should help me.

But this was not helping me in getting what was required. Following was the output which I got

```
sudo /sbin/hdparm -I /dev/sda
```

Results :

```
/dev/sda:
ely used: 1
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders     SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

ATA device, with non-removable media
Standards:
        Lik  0       0
        heads           0       0
        sectors/track   0       0
        --
        Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
        IORDY not likely
        Cannot perform double-word IO
        R/W multiple sector transfer: not supported
        DMA: not supported
        PIO: pio0
```

Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: `lsblk -do name,model,serial,rev /dev/sda`  no need to be root, easy to format/parse the output etc; see man page and `--help` for more details

Comment: I think you need to add the operating system and version you are using. For example, the `hdparam` for me on RHEL6 gives exactly the information you are looking, whereas the `lsblk` referenced in a comment above does not work as some columns are not available. The `lshw -class disk` also seems to work for me (though it gives some erroneous information in the capabilities), but IIRC it is not a standard package install.

Comment: @KevinO When you say operating system and version should be added can you please elaborate on this. And as you said 'serial' and 'rev' flags are not working in 'lsblk'

Comment: I was suggesting the information be added to the question (and/or tags). Are you using Ubuntu, CentOS, Fedora? What release? As I was noting, in RedHat Enterprise (RHEL) version 6, the `lsblk` as suggested by @don_crissti does not support the `serial` or `rev` columns. The `lshw` program suggested in an answer below is an optional package in RHEL6 not installed by default. Thus, to fully answer the question would require knowing the O/S you are using in order to know if, for example, `lsblk` could address your needs. If you have tried it and it works -- great.

Answer (score 1):

`lshw -class disk` yields in part:

```
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: WDC WD20EARS-00M
       vendor: Western Digital
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: AB51
       serial: WD-W[REDACTED]
       size: 1863GiB (2TB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=8e8f2916-5fc4-41ce-9430-30d7fe0c03ab logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
```

I believe `version` is the firmware revision, and `product` is the model number.

Comment: In my device the output for this command does not contain the columns such as `product`, `vendor`,`version` & `serial` columns. My bad I require these data alone.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`udevadm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/udevadm.8.html) `info`:

```
$ udevadm info /dev/sda
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:03:00.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:...
N: sda
S: disk/by-id/scsi-c250523c020fe61ec6913ee42aa060f8b
S: disk/by-id/wwn-0x250523c020fe61ec6913ee42aa060f8b
S: disk/by-path/pci-0000:03:00.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x250523c020fe61ec6913ee42aa060f8b /dev/d...
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sda
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:03:00.0/host2/target2:0:...
E: DEVTYPE=disk
E: ID_BUS=scsi
E: ID_MODEL=VMware_Virtual_S
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=VMware\x20Virtual\x20S
E: ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
E: ID_PART_TABLE_UUID=eda8f246
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:03:00.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_03_00_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
E: ID_REVISION=1.0
E: ID_SCSI=1
E: ID_SCSI_SERIAL=250523c020fe61ec6913ee42aa060f8b
E: ID_SERIAL=c250523c020fe61ec6913ee42aa060f8b
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=250523c020fe61ec6913ee42aa060f8b
E: ID_TYPE=disk
E: ID_VENDOR=VMware_
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=VMware\x2c\x20
E: ID_WWN=0x250523c020fe61ec
E: ID_WWN_VENDOR_EXTENSION=0x6913ee42aa060f8b
E: ID_WWN_WITH_EXTENSION=0x250523c020fe61ec6913ee42aa060f8b
E: MAJOR=8
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=1867167
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a read error (`SG_IO: bad/missing sense data`) when `hdparm` tried to get the data. This is why the output is nonsense, and contains a lot of zeros.

Look at the output of `dmesg` (last lines directly after the read error happened) to possibly figure out details of what went wrong.

You can also try `hdparm -i /dev/sda` (lower case `i` instead of capital `I`), this will display the Model and Serial information the kernel stored at boot time. It's possible that this also went wrong, because a similar error happened at boot time, but it's worth a try.

If your hard drive is broken in some way and doesn't support the commands to get the vendor/model/serial information, then you won't be able to get it.